# how to use variable in a variable name

Tags: javascript, variables

so i am working with a json variable like this:

```
opponentInvData.item1
```

it contains items 1 through 6

i need to access the different items dynamically and set them to null. itemNum is the specific item i need to access. im trying to use the eval function

```
var itemNum = 2;
eval(opponentInvData.item + itemNum + ' = ""');
```

needless to say, it's not working, any ideas?

Comment: You need to add quotations around `opponentInvData.item` in the `eval` call, otherwise it will use the current value. You shouldn't use this approach regardless - just saying what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 6):

```
opponentInvData['item1'] = "my item"
```

is the same as

```
opponentInvData.item1 = "my item"
```